# Binary coded GA with NSGA-II in R

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I have a multiobjective minimization function. I want to use NSGA-II in R. There are packages for this: nsga2R and mco. But these packages do not support binary coded chromosomes. In my fitness function I need binary chromosomes to achive best solution because of my problem's structure. Is there any way to use binary coded chromosome in nsga2 (or maybe with different algorithm) for R? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem so I decided to fix it on my own. But no guarentee if it's the right way.

The following part is for the package **'mco'** 
I copied parts out of the offical nsga2 implementation into the 'mco' package.
This workaround is only for binary (0-1) variables.

**1.** In /src/nsga2.c rewrite the functions as follows:

```html
static void mutate_ind (nsga2_ctx *ctx, individual *ind) {
  int j;
  double prob;
  GetRNGstate();
  for (j = 0; j < ctx->input_dim; j++)
    {
    //for (k=0; k < ctx[j]->input_dim; k++)
    //{
      //prob = randomperc();
      prob = unif_rand();
      if (prob <= ctx->mutation_probability) {
        if (ind->input[j] == 0)
        {
          ind->input[j] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
          ind->input[j] = 0;
        }
        ctx->input_mutations+=1;
      }
    //}
  }
  PutRNGstate();
```

then

```html
static void crossover (nsga2_ctx *ctx,
                       individual *parent1, individual *parent2,
                       individual *child1, individual *child2) {

  
  int i;
  int nbits=1;
  double rand;
  int temp, site1, site2, temp2, temp3;
  
  GetRNGstate();
  
    rand=unif_rand();
    if (rand <= ctx->crossing_probability)
    {
      ctx->input_crossings++;
      //site1 = rnd(0,ctx->input_dim);
      //site2 = rnd(0,ctx->input_dim);
      if(unif_rand()<=0.5){
        temp2=0;
      }else{
        temp2=1;
      }
      
      if(unif_rand()<=0.5){
        temp3=0;
      }else{
        temp3=1;
      }
      
      site1=temp2;
      site2=temp3;
      
      if (site1 > site2)
      {
        temp = site1;
        site1 = site2;
        site2 = temp;
      }
      for (i=0; i<site1; i++)
      {
        child1->input[i] = parent1->input[i];
        child2->input[i] = parent2->input[i];
      }
      for (i=site1; i<site2; i++)
      {
        child1->input[i] = parent2->input[i];
        child2->input[i] = parent1->input[i];
      }
      for (i=site2; i<nbits; i++)
      {
        child1->input[i] = parent1->input[i];
        child2->input[i] = parent2->input[i];
      }
    }
    else
    {
      for (i=0; i<nbits; i++)
      {
        child1->input[i] = parent1->input[i];
        child2->input[i] = parent2->input[i];
      }
    }

  PutRNGstate();
}
```

and

```html
static void population_initialize(nsga2_ctx *ctx, population *pop) {
  GetRNGstate();
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < pop->size; ++i)  {
    for (j=0; j<ctx->input_dim; ++j) {
      /* Generate random value between lower and upper bound */
      //double delta = ctx->upper_input_bound[j] - ctx->lower_input_bound[j];
      //pop->ind[i].input[j] = ctx->lower_input_bound[j] + delta*unif_rand();
   if(unif_rand() <= 0.5){
    pop->ind[i].input[j] = 0;
   }
   else{
    pop->ind[i].input[j] = 1;
   }
    }
  }
  PutRNGstate();
}
```

**2.** define the function randomperc() as follows

```html
double seed;
double oldrand[55];
int jrand;

/* Create next batch of 55 random numbers */
void advance_random ()
{
  int j1;
  double new_random;
  for(j1=0; j1<24; j1++)
  {
    new_random = oldrand[j1]-oldrand[j1+31];
    if(new_random<0.0)
    {
      new_random = new_random+1.0;
    }
    oldrand[j1] = new_random;
  }
  for(j1=24; j1<55; j1++)
  {
    new_random = oldrand[j1]-oldrand[j1-24];
    if(new_random<0.0)
    {
      new_random = new_random+1.0;
    }
    oldrand[j1] = new_random;
  }
}

/* Fetch a single random number between 0.0 and 1.0 */
double randomperc()
{
  jrand++;
  if(jrand>=55)
  {
    jrand = 1;
    advance_random();
  }
  return((double)oldrand[jrand]);
}
```

**3.** replace every unif_rand() with randomperc() in 'nsga2.c'

**4.** build the package in R